# Google Distance Matrix returning empty array of object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

I'm trying to combine Google's distance matrix and places library where I would first search for police station around my origin in which it would return me the latitude and longitude of each police station where i would append each of the values into an array to pass it to distanceMatrix destination. As of now there isn't any error but when i tried to log the results from the callback function it returns me an empty array of objects.

**Current Issue**

When trying to log the results from the callback function of distanceMatrixService, it returns an empty array of objects

[image: emptyArray]

**Normally it should look like this**
[image: valid response]

**Codes**

The codes are quite lengthy but every parts are essential and are interconnected to each other.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY_HERE&libraries=places"></script>


var map;
var infoWindow;
var markers = [];
var serviceMatrix

//Array Containing all lng/lat of police station
var allPoliceLocation = [];
var origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(3.120231, 101.595247);

//Default Dummy Data
// var destinationA = new google.maps.LatLng(3.117386, 101.635133);
// var destinationB = new google.maps.LatLng(3.117386, 101.635333);

function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: origin1
    });

    var request = {
        location: origin1,
        radius: 3000,
        types: ["police"]
    };

    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLat = place.geometry.location.lat();
    var placeLng = place.geometry.location.lng();

    createLatLng(placeLat, placeLng);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location
    });

    var homeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
            lat: 3.120231,
            lng: 101.595247
        },
        map: map,
        icon: {
            url:
                "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png"
        }
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(homeMarker, "click", function () {
        infoWindow.setContent(place.name);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
        infoWindow.setContent(place.name);
        infoWindow.open(map, this);
    });

    return marker;
}

function createLatLng(lat, lng) {
    var newLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    allPoliceLocation.push(newLocation);
}


(function () {

    //This does returns all the object of LatLng created from createLatLng function
    console.log(allPoliceLocation);
    serviceMatrix = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    serviceMatrix.getDistanceMatrix(
        {
            origins: [origin1],
            destinations: allPoliceLocation,
            travelMode: "DRIVING",
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: true
        },
        function (status,results) {

            //Returns empty array here 
            console.log(results);

            //Invalid Request
            console.log(status);
        }
    );
})();


function callback(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

            //Create a new marker for every new police station
            markers.push(createMarker(results[i]));
        }
    }

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

**EDIT**

I have added a second param to the callback function to check the status and it returned `INVALID_REQUEST`. I have also tried manually adding my 2 dummy data into an array and passing it as the destination arr while logging it and it seems to be different compared to my allPoliceLocation array.

[image: allPoliceArray empty]

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

Managed to find a "hacky" way to solved it, apparently i suspected that the distanceMatrix function ran before the data had been pushed into the array which is why it shows an empty array. Here is how i solved it.

```
var allPoliceLocation = [];

function createLatLng(results) {

    results.forEach(result => {
        const lat = result.geometry.location.lat();
        const lng = result.geometry.location.lng();


        newLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

        allPoliceLocation.push(newLocation);

    });

    getMatrixDistance(allPoliceLocation);
}

function getMatrixDistance(destination) {

    console.log("here");
    serviceMatrix = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    serviceMatrix.getDistanceMatrix(
        {
            origins: [origin1],
            destinations: destination,
            travelMode: "DRIVING",
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: true
        },
        function (results, status) {

            console.log(results);

        }
    )
}


function callback(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

            //Create a new marker for every new police station
            markers.push(createMarker(results[i]));

        }
        createLatLng(results);
    }
}
```